# How to add animation to `ng-repeat` with custom template

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate

In my `directive` I am using `ng-repeate` on custom `directive`. in the custom `directive` i am using `$compile` method as well.

On load i need to add the animation. as well when user click the animation need to appear.

In this case how to apply the `ngAnimation` to element. i tried using :

```
 $animate.addClass(element.find('div'), 'show', function () {
        scope.$apply();
      });
```

But not works.

Here is my full code of `directive`.

```
myApp.directive("newArray", function ($compile) {

  return {

    scope : {
      value : "=",
      index : "=",
      update:"&"
    },

    link : function (scope, element, attrs) {

      var getTemplate = function (value, index) {

        switch(index) {

          case 0 :
            return '<div ng-click="update()">I am here {{index}} {{value.name}}</div>'
            break;

            case 1 :
            return $('<div />', {
              class:'blue',
              html : "<h1>testing{{index}} {{value.name}}</h1>",
              click : function () {
                scope.update({num: scope.value.num});
              }
            });
            break;

            case 2 :
            return $('<div />', {
              class:'green',
              html : "<h1>testing{{index}} {{value.name}}</h1>",
              click : function () {
                scope.update({num: scope.value.num});
              }
            });
            break;

        }

      }

      element.html(getTemplate(scope.value, scope.index));
      $compile(element.contents())(scope);

      $animate.addClass(element.find('div'), 'show', function () {
        scope.$apply();
      });


    }

  }

})
```

[Demo in Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/gtQjhEbq5TjBzqaJZXdO?p=preview)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try adding the class 'show' to ng-repeat. I think the animation works if the class for which css (enter/leave) is specified is at the same element as ng-repeat.

For the animation to work on page load, initialize the array empty array and then set the value on timeout.

```
In template:
<div class="new-array" index="$index" update="update(value)"    value="value" ng-repeat="value in values">{{value.name}}</div>

In directive:
restrict: 'EAC',
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/DA2hTrySj7WDkRFPEkcq?p=preview

Note: If I restrict the directive to class it works.

Comment: I don't know what happen now, the next set of data are appending instead of replacing the old.. - can seen that?

Comment: I had set long duration 4s for transition. Hence you were seeing both. Here is the updated fiddle with changes to transition timing. http://plnkr.co/edit/DA2hTrySj7WDkRFPEkcq?p=preview

Comment: Yes, agree. is it not possible using `directive` element. now i had extra wrapping div on each of existing `div`, it will affect my `html` design pattern.

Comment: Actually the problem was with my Chrome version. It works fine if the directive is set as element. I checked it in firefox and it works fine with directive as element. Please check it.